# How to check the return type of a http call in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, firebase, types, google-cloud-functions

### Problem:

Not sure whether this matters but I am dealing with Firebase cloud functions.

Suppose I have the following function:

```
function giveMeAnInteger(): number {
    return 123;
}
```

And I call the function with:

```
function call() {
    const result = giveMeAnInteger();
    console.log(result.split(" "));
}
```

Typescript can check the return type statically, and complain "Property 'split' does not exist on type 'number'."
Now let's say I have a similar function that is published to firebase's cloud functions

```
export const giveMeAnInteger = functions.https.onCall((): number => {
    return 123;
});
```

Typescript is not able to infer the type of the response when I call the cloud function, which might lead to potential runtime errors:

```
const giveMeAnInteger = httpsCallable(functions, "giveMeAnInteger");

export function test() {
    giveMeAnInteger().then((result) => {
        const res = result.data
        console.log(res.split(" "));
    });
}
```

I got the error "'res' is of type 'unknown'." because this is the type signature of httpsCallable: `HttpsCallable<unknown, unknown>`

#### Attempt 1:

Firsly, I can declare the type before the function call itself as such:

```
const giveMeAnInteger = httpsCallable<void, number>(functions, "giveMeAnInteger");

export function test() {
    giveMeAnInteger().then((result) => {
        const res = result.data
        console.log(res.split(" "));
    });
}
```

If I do this, typescript now gives the correct complaint. However, this negates the benefit of typescript as it now relies on the user on the client side to "set" the function's return type, it also requires the client to know the implementation detail of the cloud function. If I mistakenly set the return type as a string instead:

```
const giveMeAnInteger = httpsCallable<void, string>(functions, "giveMeAnInteger");

export function test() {
    giveMeAnInteger().then((result) => {
        const res = result.data
        console.log(res.split(" "));
    });
}
```

Typescript does not complain, but there will be a runtime error since the function returns an integer instead of a string.
I want to be able to tell typescript that "if this http call is successful, this is the type that is going to be returned". And type errors should be caught in compile time.

#### Attempt 2:

I can "hardcode" the return type of the cloud function and export it:

```
export const giveMeAnInteger = functions.https.onCall((): number => {
    return 123;
});

export type ReturnTypeOfGiveMeAnInteger = number;
```

I can then import it before the function call and do something like this:

```
import { ReturnTypeOfGiveMeAnInteger } from ...

export function test() {
    giveMeAnInteger().then((result) => {
        const res = result.data as ReturnTypeOfGiveMeAnInteger
        console.log(res.split(" "));
    });
}
```

Now the static checking is correct, and I can treat the cloud function as a black box without knowing its implementation. The chance for human error is also lowered since I am declaring the type at the location where I created the function. However, this solution does not sit well with me because it feels too hacky, or "hardcode-y".

I wanted to be able to get the Type of the http call when it is successful. And I want to do so in a non-hacky way. The client is not supposed to know the implementation detail of the cloud function.
Do you have any other potential solutions that I can try? I would be happy to share more details as requested.

Comment: You are (implicitly) asking for something that isn't logically possible: Typescript can't statically verify at the time you build your app what sort of data you're going to get over the wire at *runtime*. You could *always* get something unexpected from an HTTP call. **Always**. You *must* validate at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript can't staticlly infer the return type of a callable function from the caller's point of view.  The client and server code are completely unrelated to each other as far as the TypeScript compiler is able to see, as it doesn't have any understanding of how the return data is serialized and deserialized by the Firebase SDK (anything could happen along the way - the compiler cannot be sure of it).  As such, all callable functions return `unknown`, and you must cast it to the desired type just as you are now.  There are no workarounds to this that make this any easier in a pure TypeScript implementation.

If you want more of a guarantee about the structure and contents of the return type, use a runtime type schema such as [zod](https://zod.dev/) to verify that the return data matches what you expect the backend to send.